# Article and preposition for foreign universities

Tags: usage, preposition, article

I'm curious as to what article/preposition one should use to refer to studying at a university, such as Stanford University (in the USA).

Which ones are correct if I want to say "I study at Stanford (University)"? Should I use `an` or `bei`, and should I put in a definite article or not?

> (a) Ich studiere an Stanford.
>
> (b) Ich studiere bei Stanford.
>
> (c) Ich studiere an der Stanford Universität.
>
> (d) Ich studiere bei der Stanford Universität.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(c) Ich studiere an der Stanford-Universität.

or

Ich studiere in Stanford.  (a) and (b) are not ok.

EDIT: I agree that a hyphen is better in the case of (c).

Comment: (d) is also wrong. The word order in (c) seems unnatural in German (at least to me), you'd rather say `Ich studiere an der Universität Stanford`. In any case you'd have to add a hyphen in writing: `Ich studiere an der Stanford-Universität`. Alternatively you may keep the original as it's a proper name: `Ich studiere an der Stanford University`.

Comment: Sounds very natural to me, but I'm used to "Ich studiere an der Bauhaus-Universität" so I guess I just got used to it. But in contrast to Stanford, "Bauhaus-Universität" is  a "brand name". So if you want you be very correct, you are right.

Comment: Since Stanford is [not really a place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanford,_California), but rather [a person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leland_Stanford), *in Stanford* may be considered wrong.